# Is server side validation mandatory by google in recaptcha?

Tags: recaptcha

I have a website where i have implemented google recaptcha, however it does not have server side validation. I want to know if google mandates server side validation. I have search through web but did not found anything on this.
Any supporting document/link on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Google does not force to perform the server-side validation but this is a necessary step if you want to ensure you are protected.

If you implement a client-side only validation it means there is still a request to your backend which does not enforce the captcha validation, and potentially can be exploited.

Here is an [example](https://codeforgeek.com/google-recaptcha-tutorial/) where at server-side the validation is executed before the action (post comment, save user details, etc..) is performed.